# Saving Mathjax generated SVG

Tags: support, mathjax

This concerns rendering SVG in Mathjax via the context menu "Math Settings" -> "Math Renderer" -> "SVG". This works fine in the browser but I'd like to save a .svg file to my computer. Right clicking on the equation brings up the Mathjax context menu but I can't see a way to save the rendering to a file. How do I obtain a `.svg` file I can include elsewhere?

Comment: Although this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924033/convert-latex-mathml-to-svg-or-image-with-mathjax-or-similar) itself is rather old, it has a second Answer from last year (2019).  I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: If it's rendered in a browser, you can't just lift the SVG element from the HTML source?  I'm not completely sure what a valid .svg file contains. Maybe it's not what I think.